# Setting cookies for the GeckoFX web browser?

Tags: c#, .net, cookies, geckofx

How do you set the cookies for the Gecko web browser?

I know that I have to call:

```
geckowebbrowser.Document.Cookie = ...;
```

but you need to set the cookies globally too.  For example, in the .NET included Microsoft IE WebBrowserControl you set them by using the following Winapi function:

```
static extern bool InternetSetCookie(string lpszUrl, string lpszCookieName,
                                     string lpszCookieData);
```

This works fine for IE Web Browser but not for Gecko.

I've tried to use the Cookiemanager class from the Gecko library by calling Cookiemanager.add(...)

Comment: what version of geckofx/firefox/xulrunner are you using? It would be easier to help if you posted you code in which you tried to use CookeManager.Add(...)

Comment: I am using GeckoFx-14.0-0.2 and xulrunner 14.0.1 I used the following code once per cookie variable                  
CookieManager.Add(url, url, cookiename, value, secure,httponly, 0);

Comment: I don't know how and if this class is associated with the GeckoFx control. I haven't found any description how to use this class

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me with geckofx browser 29.0:

```
string cookieName = "testName";
string cookieValue = "testValue";
geckoBrowser.Document.Cookie = string.Format("{0}={1}; {2}", cookieName, cookieValue, mainBrowser.Document.Cookie);
```

This updates or creates a cookie.